# Overloading operator+ with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I'm working on a project on polymorphism in C++ and I have lots of pointers. I need to overload the operator +, so that I can write the following expression naturally:

```
c=a+b;
```

with a,b and c being declared as:

```
A *a,*b,*c;
```

The basic overloading definitions I know are

```
A &operator+(const A& a)
A &operator=(const A& a)
```

but I get the following errors:

**invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'A&' from an rvalue of type 'A* const'
invalid operands of types 'A*' and 'A*' to binary 'operator+'**

How should I write the overloaded operator so that I can call it naturally?

Comment: Just dereference those pointers when calling the overloaded operator: `*c=*a+*b;` You cannot overload global operators for intrinsic types like pointers.

Comment: You likely want to overload `A &operator+=(const A& a)` - `A &operator+(const A& a)` is likely wrong

Comment: Are you adding pointers or the objects they are pointing to?  Adding pointers doesn't make sense.  Adding a scalar quantity to a pointer is more sensible.

Comment: I want to add the objects they are pointing to. @πάντα ῥεῖ 's idea is the only one that works so far; I understand there's no way to have c=a+b,without dereferencing.

Comment: @flaviumanica _"I understand there's no way to have c=a+b,without dereferencing."_ That's exactly my point, there's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator is a special member method (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator) and C++ dont allow operator override over pointers after his first standard (before, some implementations allow to do that).

Comment: the assignment operator observation is a bit of a red herring. Given `class Foo{}; Foo a; int b; b =a ;`  you can't overload the assignment operator for `int` but you can add `Foo::operator int` instead.

Comment: @MSalters what I attempt to explain is that since the assigment operator only can be overrided as member of any class, the expression x=y must hold a lvalue (x) with class type not pointer type. May be the override of the assignment operator is not necessary at all.

Comment: Then I understood you correctly. The logic is still flawed. The expression ` x=y` is also valid when `x` is an lvalue of pointer type, and `y` is a class type whose class has a conversion to the (pointer) type of `x` (or possibly less cv-qualified).

Comment: I review the question, and you are right. I read too fast and understood that he wanted to overload also the assignment operator ... my bad ...

Comment: Actually, the `operator+` presented here has a similar problem: at least one of the two arguments has to have class type.

Comment: @MSalters, you are right! I'm very confused. I remember to do things like that in my old LCIII with Symantec C++ twenty years ago. It's possible that new standards changed that?

Comment: It's been illegal since the first C++98 standard, 17 years ago.

Comment: But the first commercial version was in october 1985 ... ok. I've used C++ before standard... ;) ... I rewrite my comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know that my following suggestion is probably not what you want, but for the sake of completeness I tried to find a solution with a template wrapper class around pointers which *would*  permit overloading operator+. I wondered what exactly the combination of lookup rules, template arguments and type conversion could achieve. It turns out that the "natural" use of `operator+` seems impossible, but an explicit call works. Here is my code:

```
/** A wrapper class around arbitrary pointer types */
template<class TPtr> class MyPtrT
{
    public:
    TPtr ptr;
    MyPtrT(const TPtr p = 0) :ptr(p)    
    {}
};

/** A plus operator on all MyPtrTs */
template<class T> 
const MyPtrT<T>& 
operator+(const MyPtrT<T> &l, const MyPtrT<T> &r) 
{ 
    return l; 
}

MyPtrT<int *> mp1, mp2, mp3;
int *ip;
```

Ok, what works with these declarations?

```
// This works (template type explicit) ...
mp3 = operator+<int *>(ip, ip);

// ... and this works (of course,
// arguments match template declaration) ...
mp3 = mp1 + mp2;
```

And what doesn't (with gcc 4.8.3)?

```
mp3 = mp1 + ip;
```

The error is:

```
smartpointplus.cpp:33:12: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘MyPtrT<int*>’ and ‘int*’)
  mp3 = mp1 + ip;
            ^
smartpointplus.cpp:33:12: note: candidate is:
smartpointplus.cpp:13:1: note: template<class T> const MyPtrT<T>& operator+(const MyPtrT<T>&, const MyPtrT<T>&)
 operator+(const MyPtrT<T> &l, const MyPtrT<T> &r)
 ^
smartpointplus.cpp:13:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
smartpointplus.cpp:33:14: note:   mismatched types ‘const MyPtrT<T>’ and ‘int*’
```

I'm not quite sure why the compiler doesn't construct a MyPtrT from the int* argument. It does see the proper function. Perhaps something is wrong with my ctor?

```
mp3 = operator+(ip, ip);
```

The error message is similar. The template function is considered but the compiler cannot convert the arguments.

```
smartpointplus.cpp:36:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator+(int*&, int*&)’
  mp3 = operator+(ip, ip);
                        ^
smartpointplus.cpp:36:24: note: candidate is:
smartpointplus.cpp:13:1: note: template<class T> const MyPtrT<T>& operator+(const MyPtrT<T>&, const MyPtrT<T>&)
 operator+(const MyPtrT<T> &l, const MyPtrT<T> &r)
 ^
smartpointplus.cpp:13:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
smartpointplus.cpp:36:24: note:   mismatched types ‘const MyPtrT<T>’ and ‘int*’
  mp3 = operator+(ip, ip);
```

It's a bit sad that `operator+(ip, ip)` (automatically trying to deduce the template type) doesn't work. That limits usability ;-). One would have to templatize all functions using that operator in order to avoid providing the template type explicitly for every call. The *infix* notation below, by contrast, doesn't even consider the template operator:

```
mp3 = ip + ip;
```

The error message is short:

```
smartpointplus.cpp:38:13: error: invalid operands of types ‘int*’ and ‘int*’ to binary ‘operator+’
  mp3 = ip + ip;
```

I always thought that infix and function style notation of operator calls are just, well, notational differences, but apparently they also change the lookup rules.

tl;dr: What the OP wanted (an infix plus operation with pointer arguments)  doesn't work even with a template wrapping class, afaict.